# Google Docs thinks that I am using an Apple keyboard even though I'm not (non-Chrome browser)

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using the Gnome Web browser on Linux which happens to be my favorite browser. I'm having an issue with all Google Docs applications where it assumes I'm using an Apple keyboard when I'm not. This means that I cannot copy/paste with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> because it's looking for a <kbd>⌘</kbd> key which I do not have. When I use and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> it jumps to the beginning and end of the line instead of jumping between words. This makes it a pain to edit anything. Is there a way to manually set the input to PC keyboard or do I need to change something in my user agent string?

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Safari/605.1.15
```

Comment: did you try other browser?

Comment: Yes it works in Chrome and Firefox and previous versions of Gnome Web (epiphany).